# Swipe in Scrollview is not working all time

Tags: android, scrollview, gesturedetector

I have one layout in which i have used `ScrollView`. 
Now I have also implemented 'CustomScrollView' so that i can filter **Swipe** action that view.

Here is my custom ScrollView :

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction
    class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have also implemeted `GestureDetector`.
On swiping view vill call `onFling` 80/100 times.

Can I have some suggestions so that i can implement more accurate **swipe** behaviour.?

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem of `onFling()` not getting called lies in the fact that `CustomScrollView` sometimes also intercepts horizontal gestures/scrolling?

I would try using this small class, which was made to better filter out horizontal gestures and then hook up your `GestureDetector`:

```java
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private float mHorizontalDistance;
    private float mVerticalDistance;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mHorizontalDistance = mVerticalDistance = 0f;
            mPreviousX = ev.getX();
            mPreviousY = ev.getY();
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            mHorizontalDistance += Math.abs(curX - mPreviousX);
            mVerticalDistance += Math.abs(curY - mPreviousY);
            mPreviousX = curX;
            mPreviousY = curY;
            if (mHorizontalDistance > mVerticalDistance) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Combining scrollviews and gestures can be a hard task requiring multiple tweaks and adjustments for a specific case. I'm pretty sure in the filtering part (because it's tried and tested in the production environment), not so sure about the part where the gesture detector comes in, this requires testing.

Comment: It says `mGestureDetector` is never initialized. How can i initialize it ?

Comment: @AndiGeeky the same way you did in your code (in constructor); I didn't paste the constructor part in my snippet for brevity

Comment: @ Android777 : Ohk..Thanks.!!